# Software to organize/save Links/Bookmarks offline

Tags: text-editor, information-management, bookmark

I search for a software to help me organize many links in an orderly fashion. (could be a good text editor or an outliner)

The websites are to be saved as hyperlinks with a short note besides them and classified by a subject, could be with colours, tree structure, tabs or anything else.

Offline, locally stored, free and preferably without any account (especially not something like a facebook,google,evernote or microsoft account).

I don't want something with too many features, no calendar, no email, no cloud or sync etc

Extremely simple way to organize my bookmarks as hyperlinks offline and in small bundles. If possible please give as many options as possible.

Comment: You surfing the web so you have a web browser.  Firefox has a built-in tools, SHIFT CTRL B, has most of the features you want, and definitely stores your bookmarks offline.  From said bookmark manager you can export to HTML if you want to.  Have you considered this built-in tool?